# PDO - Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql

How to Fix this issue?

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

I use UNIQUE KEY on My Table

```
CREATE TABLE `blog` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `str` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`),
  UNIQUE KEY `str` (`str`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

if I enter the same data for times I got this error

if I create datable without UNIQUE KEY it's working well

My PDO Insert code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO blog(title,str) VALUES(:title,:str)";
 $stmt = $DBcon->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindparam(':title', $title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindparam(':str', $str,PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();
```

if I remove the `$stmt->execute();` the UNIQUE KEY concept working well

I tried on MYSQLI it works without any issue But in PDO I got this error

Comment: Well, it throws an Exception, because you set the table to UNIQUE, so it is not possible to set the same value multiple times for the same field. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: you are right I use UNIQUE to avoiding the Duplicate entries but in MYSQLI it works well but in PDO I got this error

Comment: Are you sure you're inserting exactly the same values (that already exists) when using mysqli and pdo?

Comment: in MYSQLI it working well in PDO while inserting the same value i got this error

Comment: perhaps set it as a composite unique key on the two columns rather than two individual unique keys - or `insert ignore into.... `

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE INTO blog(title,str) VALUES(:title,:str)` working fine with UNIQUE KEY

Answer (score 0):

you have define `unique key` for `title` and `str` so it not allow insert `duplicate value` in this field

```
 UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`),
 UNIQUE KEY `str` (`str`)
```

The UNIQUE constraint ensures that all values in a column are different.

Both the UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints provide a guarantee for uniqueness for a column or set of columns.

A PRIMARY KEY constraint automatically has a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: yes but it works fine on MYSQLI in PDO I got this Error